k0 grinding for anti-covert channel signing
In the post by Pieter Wuille on anti-covert channel signing technique, there is mention of k0 grinding technique which can be exploited by a malicious HW to expose few bits of secret marterial per signature. It mentions:
in Scheme 2 it can try many different k0 values (by deviating from k0=H(d,m,t)), and 
observe what the resulting (R,s) signature will be. For example, by iterating on average 
256 times, it can choose 8 bits in (R,s) that convey information about k, d, or whatever 
seed or master key they are derived from. Using forward error correction (FEC) schemes, 
this channel of a few bits per signature may be enough to leak an entire seed over enough 
signatures

Can someone please elaborate on how specifically k0 values can be deviated from H(d,m,t) and how the bits can be used to leak secret information using the FEC scheme. Any pointers to code samples will be much appreciated.
